# Show text input line by line

Tags: javascript

How do I display the input parameter like this:

```
  displayText("you and me");
  expected output:
  ["you and me", "you and", "and me", "you", "and", "me"]
```

I have tried like the following code, but the results are still wrong. My code is like this now.

```
 let displayText = (txt) => {
   let output= []
   for(let i = 0; i < txt.length; i++) {
       for(j = i + 1; j < txt.length + 1; j++) {
          output.push(txt.slice(i, j))
       }
   }
   return output
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You will need to `split()` the string on the word breaks to have your function work as is (and also declare `j`).

```js
let displayText = (txt) => {
  txt = txt.split(' ');
  
  let output = []
  for (let i = 0; i < txt.length; i++) {
    for (let j = i + 1; j < txt.length + 1; j++) {
      output.push(txt.slice(i, j).join(' '))
    }
  }
  
  return output
}

console.log(displayText("you and me"))
```

To return an array sorted by combination length, you can group each `slice()` by word count and `flat()` the output array before returning.

```js
let displayText = (txt) => {
  txt = txt.split(' ');

  let
    len = txt.length, output = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < len; i++) {
    for (let j = i + 1; j < len + 1; j++) {
      (output[len - (j - i)] ??= []).push(txt.slice(i, j).join(' '))
    }
  }
  // before flat() call
  // [ [ 'you and me' ], [ 'you and', 'and me' ], [ 'you', 'and', 'me' ] ]
  return output.flat()
}

console.log(displayText("you and me"));
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all you can split the sentence:

```
const sentence = 'you and me'
const parts = sentence.split(' ')
```

The difficult part is to extract the elements by pairs. Use `slice` for this:

```
   const numberOfPairs = parts.length - 1
   for (let i=0; i<numberOfPairs ; i++) {
      console.log(parts.slice(i, i+2).join(' '))
   }
```

Then, print the individual parts:

```
  parts.forEach(part => console.log(part))
```

Answer (score 0):

first you have to split sentence
Example:-

```
var strArr = string.split(" ");
var output= []    
var temp = "";
 for (var i = 0; i < strArr.length; i++) {
        temp = strArr[i];        
        output.push(temp)
            for (var j = i + 1; j < strArr.length; j++) {
                temp += strArr[j];
                output.push(temp)
            }
    }
    console.log(output)
```

You may do like this.